# Wiedemann-Franz law generalized to quantum Hall effects in electronic systems

Tags: topological-insulators, quantum-hall-effect, chern-simons-theory, insulators

Wiedemann-Franz law states a relation in a conductor between the thermal and electric conductivities by their ratio as $\kappa/\sigma=LT$ where $T$ is the temperature and $L$ is the Lorenz number which is a constant.

Let us restrict the condition to be purely (fermionic) electronic systems (without any phonon or bosonic contribution) with $U(1)_Q$-charge conservation respected by Hamiltonian. My question is whether we could generalize this law to quantum Hall effects, e.g. in Chern insulators.

In my understanding, the answer might be positive in the sense that we should modify the law. Since the Hall conductivities of quantum Hall materials can be thought of as from the boundary currents, we can spontaneously break $U(1)_Q$ down to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ at the boundary such that the boundary current can be neutral. Then the Hall conductance will be purely thermal although the Hamiltonian of the whole system explicitly respects $U(1)_Q$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Kane and Fisher paper (https://www.physics.upenn.edu/~kane/pubs/p25.pdf)?

Comment: @d_b Many thanks for the useful reference! Actually, I did not make the title precise. I want to know whether there is some system (whose Hamiltonian respects charge conservation and has only electrons as its fundamental degrees of freedom) can realize an integer Hall effect breaking the Wiedemann-Franz law.